# Loopback and MongoDB Embedded Documents Defining JSON Model

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

Can / how do you define an embedded document in a model's json definition with LoopbackJS without creating a model to represent the sub-document?

For example, consider this following MongoDB document:

```
 {
      _id: ObjectId("some_mongodb_id"),
      subDocs: [
           {
                "propertyA": "a1",
                "propertyB": "b1"
           },
           {
                "propertyA": "a2",
                "propertyB": "b2"
           }
      ]
 }
```

I could create two models in loopback:

```
 some-model.json:
      ...
      "properties": {
           "subDocs": [
                "SubDocsModel"
           ]
      }

 sub-docs-model.json:
      ...
      "properties": {
           "propertyA": "string",
           "propertyB": "string"
      }
```

Rather than doing that, however, I'd like to just declare the `sub-doc` model inline in the `some-model.json` since it's just there to document the shape of `some-model`'s document.

Is that possible? Something like:

```
 some-model.json:
 ...
 "properties":{
      "subDocs": [
           {
                "propertyA": {
                     "type": "string"
                },
                "propertyB": {
                     "type": "string"
                }
           }
      ]
 }
```

I tried the above, but what I end up with is a field in my mongodb document that's of type `string` with the value `[object Object]`...

The purpose would be (1) to document the shape of the sub-document, and (2) to allow for validation by loopback without adding custom logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as an `object`

*some-model.json:*

```
"properties": {
       "subDocs": ["object"]
  }
```

But if you want validation or have a structure for sub-docs, you need to create a loopback model for that.

Loopback does not do any validation, ... for properties with type `object`.

Comment: right... but this requires that I write extra code to validate things like `propertyA` being of type `string`. Is there a way to encode the types?

Comment: @jpoveda No. If you want benefit of validation and data structure of sub-docs, you need to create a loopback model for that

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. if you update the answer with the detail about needing a model for validation, I'll mark the answer as accepted. I'll update my question to be clear about that requirement.